# How can I get google api after google identity log in?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I can login with

```
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

I have created an api key for google drive on the [console dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard). According to [Drive js api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/js). I should not put the key in a public webpage.
Is there a way to get my api key from after logging in with the account that owns the key via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An api key is used for accessing public apis.  Unless the file you are trying to access is public you are not going to be able to access it.  That tutorial also tells you to create Web application. Which will allow you to authorize your user to access their data.

> Is there a way to get my api key from after logging in with the account that owns the key via javascript?

Api keys and web application credentials as which that tutorial shows you how to create are owned by you the developer. They are used to request authorization of the users of your application.   So no there is no way that the users of your application could give you an api key that must be created by  you the developer.

## Restrict your api key

due to the fact that javascript is client side if anyone does a view source they are going to see your api key.  That is why it is a good idea to setup restriction for your key in Google clound colsone

[Apikeys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)

There are a number of ways to restrict your key

You can restrict it by API restrictions limiting what apis it can be used for.

You can set up Application restrictions which will limit things like what websites it can be used from or an ip address.

A key in production should always have restrictions applied.

[image]

Comment: no my question is not about users accessing the key... its about the key owner getting his key so that i dont put it on my code

Comment: The key owner is the developer of the application.  As in you.   You need to put it in your code for your code to run.  If you are worried about it being in the code of your website, the solution is to lock it down by your domain they no one else will be able to use it.

Comment: so even if it can be seen its fine?#

Comment: @BretJoseph yes if you have set up retractions so that no one can use it except from your website..